# What am I missing

Tags: logic

So the answer to this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnqsh.jpg) question is E. I have 0 clues why. Can someone please explain to me?

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE! Can you please elaborate a bit which option didi you choose and why?

Comment: Why do you think $\frac  x 2$ is an even integer if $x$ is an integer?

Comment: There is no positive integer $x$ such that $x+1<2$. Therefore the premise is false in A, B, C and D, making all the statements true.

Comment: @egreg why not convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: Ironically, an argument can be made that *any* answer to this question is correct. I.e., selecting one statement as true cannot imply the unselected statements are false without leading to a contradiction based on the self-referential nature of "the" correct answer E.

Answer (score 1):

For *no* integer $x$ it holds that $x+1<2$, because this would mean
$$
0<x<1
$$

A proposition of the form “if $P$ then $Q$” where $P$ is false, is true.

In particular, the statement “$\exists x\bigl((x>0\land x+1<2) \to Q(x)\bigr)$” is true for *every* formula $Q(x)$ (where $x$ can actually appear or not). What value for $x$ can we use? Whatever we want: the statement
$$
(1>0\land 1+1<2)\to Q(1)
$$
is true. Hence each of the first four statements is true.

By the way, also the statement
$$
\forall x\bigl((x>0\land x+1<2) \to Q(x)\bigr)
$$
is true.

As [Barry Cipra rightly comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753162/what-am-i-missing/3753195#comment7719737_3753162), the question is not really well-posed, because *all* five possibilities are true. But it's a convention in such kind of tests that a choice “All of the above” is somewhat separated from the rest and is the single correct choice when “all of the above” satisfy the request.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something to do with what we call *vacuous implication* in mathematical logic. I don't know exactly where you stuck so I will try to be self-contained.

Let *A* and *B* be statements (that is, a kind of *assertion* that can either be true or false when all the variables in it, if there is any, are *not* free. For example: *A* can be the statement *there exists a positive integers x such that x+1<2*; *B* can be the statement *x=1* etc. Here *x* is a variable and the term *there exists* is a *quantifier*. Another type of quantifier that you may have seen somewhere else is *for all*. I think you could treat those quantifier as somethings that feed concrete values to the variable in the statement from some universal set in which we assume all the elements that are possibly needed for our argument could be draw from, so that the variables are fixed and the statement is forced to have a truth value).

An implication is a compound statement in the form *if A, then B.* So, as what shown in your question, all those choices are implications. An implication becomes vacuous when *A* (called the *premise*) is false. And if this is the case, no matter the statement B is true or false, we can always conclude that the implication, as a whole, is true, vacuously. The point here is that the truth value of such implication is *independent* to the statement *B* (called the *conclusion* of the implication). Thus, as all the 4 premises in the question are the same and false (since for all positive integer *x*, *x+1>2* or *x+1=2*), in principle we don't even need to look at the conclusions and can be sure that all those implications are true.

Why is vacuous implication always true?

My understanding is that if you treat whatever you are arguing logically as a system, then there are already some (maybe implicitly) statements assumed/defined to be true in the system, and thus there are also some statements assumed/defined to be false, namely, those true statement's negations (for example, we assume *1* and *2* are two different objects and thus $1=2$ is assumed to be false in the first place). When you conduct some implication, to some extent you are like asserting the premise of the implication as a true statement, and add it into your system. What is meant by the premise is false here is that there exists a true statement in your system being the negation of the premise statement prior to the addition of the premise. In such sense, your system contains a contradiction once the premise is added. And due to *[principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)*, any statement can be derived from such a system, in particular, including your vacuous implication.

Another (maybe more intuitive) way I understand vacuous implication is that, if the premise is false, then one is actually arguing something that could never happen in the current set-up. And thus, one could never argue that such implication is impossible (such implication is kinda isolated from others and add such implications into the system won't break anything). Since, in logic, we kinda have a mindset that *all that is not false, is true*, we can always treat the vacuous implication as being true.

All that I have written are based on my own understandings. **If anything I stated is incorrect, please correct me! Thanks in advance.** And there must be imprecisions since I only have very limited knowledge on logic. But after all, hope it helps a little.